# Flutter provider: why notifylisteners is not rebuilding widget of previous page when i change data in current page and go back?

Tags: flutter, provider

So i have a profile page which has edit profile button. When i go to edit profile and then i successfully edit user name and go back to profile page, the user name text is not updated. I can't figure out why the widget is not rebuilding please help.

My simiplied code:
inside profile page stateful widget build method that shows user name:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context)=>UserRepository.instance(),
  child:  Consumer<UserRepository>(
                      builder:(context,user,child)=>Text(
                            user.userName,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontSize: 20),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                    ),
);
```

inside edit profile page stateful widget:
(using ChangeNotifierProvider at top also doesnt work)

```
Consumer<UserRepository>(
                  builder: (context, user, child) => RaisedButton(
                    focusNode: editFocusNode,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(
                            "Update profile",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _onSubmit(_username.text);
                    },
                  ),
                );

Future<void> _onSubmit(String userName) async {


  bool isDone = await user.requestProfileUpdateAPI(
      context, userName);

  if (isDone) {
    _key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Successfully updated profile"),
    ));
  } else {
    _key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(user.error),
    ));
  }
}
  }
```

User Repository is

```
enum Code { Uninitialized, Done, Progress, Error }

class UserRepository with ChangeNotifier {

  Code _statusCode = Code.Uninitialized;
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  String error = '';

  SharedPreferences prefs;
  DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
  var userName;

  UserRepository.instance() {
    _checkIsAlreadyLogin();
    dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  }


  Code get statusCode => _statusCode;

  void _checkIsAlreadyLogin() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
  userName = "";
  queryUserData();
  notifyListeners();
}

Future<bool> requestProfileUpdateAPI(
  BuildContext context, String name, String phone, String address) async {
Map<String, String> body = {
  'name': name,

};

try {
  _statusCode = Code.Progress;
  notifyListeners();
  String baseUrl = await getBaseUrl();
  String token = await getToken();
  final response = await http.put(
    "$baseUrl$updateProfileUrl",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    },
    body: body,
  );
  print(response.statusCode);

  print(response.body.toString());
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    UserProfileModel user = new UserProfileModel.fromJson(responseJson);

    if (user.success) {
      print("user: $user");
      _statusCode = Code.Done;
      await updateCurrentLoginToDatabase(user);//user data is saved to database
      queryUserData();
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    error = responseJson['message'];
  }
} catch (e) {

  error = e.message;
}
_statusCode = Code.Error;
notifyListeners();

return false;
}

Future<void> queryUserData() async {
List<Map<String, dynamic>> users =
    await dbHelper.queryAllRows(DatabaseHelper.tableUser);

userName = users.first['name'];
notifyListeners();
}
}
```

In queryUserData(), i get the updated data from database but the widget is not rebuilding, i am doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you check you are passing "username" only every time to update.  onPressed: () {_onSubmit("username"); },

Comment: i have passed username and the data is also updated on the server as well. I have verified the data because the username widget is updated when app is restarted or i go to the home page and then go to profile page. The username widget is only not updated when i go from profile page to edit profile and then edit stuff and server shows success and i go back to profile page.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya thanks for the reply, username is dynamic and obtained from UI

Comment: any update  or solution??